# Position of a div relative to the window?

Tags: jquery, positioning

Trying to find the position of a div, relative to the window. I've got a horizontal div and I want to get the left value relative to the window. So If I scroll the second div to the left of the window, it will read "0".

Not sure if this is possible without a parent div. Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FSrye/

edit: it should function like this without a parent div.

http://jsfiddle.net/FSrye/1/

Comment: so would you rather use the `body`? a parent is required

Comment: What do you mean? The body of a document is a different size than the window.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try calculating it as a function of the position of the element relative to the scroll position of the window: http://jsfiddle.net/va836/

```
 var position = $('selector').position().left - $(window).scrollLeft();
```

<strike>You might also have to factor in the position relative to other elements if it's not a top level element.</strike>

Actually, it's even easier -- just use `offset()` and omit the calculation of the parents.

```
var position = $('selector').offset().left - $(window).scrollLeft();
```

Comment: For your example you might use `post.position().left + $('#wrapper').position().left - $(window).scrollLeft()` -- or the distance of the element from the edge of the window minus the current distance the window is scrolled left.

Comment: @Wes - it's even easier using `offset()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [`scrollLeft()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/) on the window to get the horizontal scroll amount.

Comment: Hm, then I think I have misunderstood your question.